# Bind checkbox with Images and Dropdownlist in Grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, gridview

I have a gridview which contains images (populated dynamically from database) and dropdownlist which contains two values. First column contains checkbox. I want to insert selected checkbox's images and dropdown values to a new table on button click. What may be the suitable way?
Here is the grid view:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" 
            EmptyDataText="No images found" OnPageIndexChanging="gvDetails_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="5">
            <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckUncheckAll"/>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID ="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">                   
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="imgPreview" ImageUrl='<%#
                        "ImageHandler.ashx?imgID="+ Eval("ID") %>' runat="server"
                            Height="80px" Width="80px" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dropdown" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="dpdListEstatus" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dpdListEstatus_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                            <asp:ListItem>A</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>B</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop with gridview rows

Find for the checkbox control

Check if its Checked property is true

If yes, call insert statement

Set the values you want to get from image and dropdownlist. Of course you need to use findcontrol on it too.

```
Dim cbSelect As CheckBox, imgToInsert As Image, ddlStatus As DropDownList
For Each r As GridViewRow In gvDetails.Rows
    cbSelect = r.Cells(0).FindControl("CheckBox2")

    If cbSelect.Checked Then
        imgToInsert = r.Cells(1).FindControl("imgPreview")
        ddlStatus = r.Cells(2).FindControl("dpdListEstatus")

        'Insert statement goes here...
    End If
Next r
```

Comment: Yes.. i was just looking for that which can relate the check boxes to the data in same row, otherwise I was trying to achieve it through asp:BoundData. Thanks a ton...