# Update gridview according to checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I have a gridview. It contains checkboxes against all the values. Once I click the checkbox, and press submit, the selected items are inserted into another databse. I want that those selected items shouldn't appear on the current gridview if loaded next time. 
For this, what I have planned is that there must be a column in current database to indicate whether the checkbox has been checked or not. The column will be filled with yes/no accordingly. And then display the rows which have only "No" in them.

However, this seems to be lengthy. Is there any other means to achieve this.

Comment: What does "next time" mean? Anytime ever?

Comment: basically, after clicking the submit button, the page reloads. And at this point, the grid view must be updated, i.e., checked items must disappear from grid view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I believe this is a continuation of your problem from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304549/bind-checkbox-with-images-and-dropdownlist-in-grid-view/25304883#25304883),

I'll just copy my answer from there.

Sorry if it's not written in c#, I just noticed that tag just now.

You need to include the Primary Key or the column that makes your record Unique in its table. I'll just assume a "ImageID" column.

Place it on a hidden field on your first column.

You'll need it to issue a SQL DELETE or UPDATE statement on those rows after insertion to the destination DB. Although by using the latter, you'll need to have a new column on the table let's say - "TRANSFER_STATUS" tinyint, a switch which you can update 1 or 0.

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                OnCheckedChanged="CheckUncheckAll"/>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID ="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfImgID" runat="server" 
                Value=<%# Eval("ImageID") %> />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Code behind:

```
Dim cbSelect As CheckBox, imgToInsert As Image
Dim ddlStatus As DropDownList, hfImgID As HiddenField

For Each r As GridViewRow In gvDetails.Rows
    cbSelect = r.Cells(0).FindControl("CheckBox2")

    If cbSelect.Checked Then
        hfImgID = r.Cells(0).FindControl("hfImgID")
        imgToInsert = r.Cells(1).FindControl("imgPreview")
        ddlStatus = r.Cells(2).FindControl("dpdListEstatus")

        /*Insert statement goes here...
        DELETE or UPDATE statement goes here, 
        passing the ID of the image from hfImgID.Value*/
    End If
Next r

**EDIT**

/*Call your SELECT statement again here to refresh your GridView.
  If you used UPDATE, you need to include 
  your toggle switch in the WHERE clause. TRANSFER_STATUS = 0*/
```

Comment: thanks for the response but i used exactly the same method, employing a hidden field. Thats the same thing I was implying in my question. I just needed some other method. By the way, I have completed this and used exactly same approach, so I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: Using classes and stored procedures might help you in making your codes short.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what DB you are using, so this is limited, but it will get the value of a cell based on the checkbox--this assumes the chkbox is in the 3rd cell(index 2) and that there is other text in cells 0 and 1 (I don't know what your DGV looks like). it then puts the cell values of the checked rows into a dataset--from there you could dump the dataset into a db of your choice (not sure what you have). In terms of not showing the row on next load, you could change the text of cell 4 (a y/n cell, for example), then update the current database. Next time you load the DGV, include in your call to show only rows with 'y' in column X (are you using SQL?)

```
 'get checked items and add to dataset
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For i = 0 To Outdgv.RowCount - 1
        If Outdgv.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = True Then
            Dim dsNewRow As DataRow
            dsNewRow = dataset.Tables("report").NewRow()
            Dim val1 As String = Outdgv.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
            Dim val2 As String = Outdgv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
            dsNewRow.Item(1) = val1
            dsNewRow.Item(2) = val2
            dataset.Tables("report").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)
            Outdgv.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = 'n'
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

From your reply to my comment, it seems a restriction during the current session is suffient. Therefore you could keep track in a session variable.

For example, if your rows have an integer id, you could store a `List<int>` in session, and add ids to the list each time a checked row is submitted. Then refer to the session variable when refreshing the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your goal appears to be, but if your trying to hide items that are checked directly from the grid that is possible.

*Query:* `SELECT * FROM [db] WHERE ([Checked] = 0);`

So the premise is that if the value is zero, it appears on the grid.  If it becomes any other value, it won't appear on the grid.

*Grid*

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBox Id="CustomerCheck" runat="server"
               Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>'
               Enabled="false" />

          <asp:LinkButton Id="lbCustomerActive" runat="server"
               Text="Activate" CommandName="OnActivate" 
               ToolTip='<%# "Activate or Deactivate Course: " + Eval("CourseId") %>'
               OnClick="CustomerCheck_Click" CssClass="Activator" />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

You'll now be able to actually write a method for server, called `CustomerCheck_Click`. That server postback will call your method which can write to the database, once that value in that column is changed the grid will no longer display it.

```
protected void CustomerCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Logic to modify column in database.
}
```